# How to make surfaces appear solid in python open 3D?

Tags: python, 3d, visualization, point-clouds, open3d

[image: Problem surface]

I'm trying to convert a point cloud into a mesh using python open3D, and I'm having trouble making the surface appear solid from all angles when I visualize (see left side of figure). My code is as follows:

```
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud()
pcd.points = o3d.utility.Vector3dVector(points)
pcd.estimate_normals()
pcd.orient_normals_towards_camera_location()
mesh, _ = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.create_from_point_cloud_poisson(pcd, depth=3)
mesh.compute_vertex_normals()
mesh.paint_uniform_color(np.array([0,191,255])/255)
```

Has anyone dealt with this problem before? I believe it must be an issue with the orientation of the surface normals. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe faces generated are single-sided. Try passing flag `mesh_show_back_face` into visualization like this `o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh], mesh_show_back_face=True)`